# read_post meta capability for anonymous users

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, permissions

`read_post` is a meta capability that can be used to check if a user can read a post. It can be used, for example, like this:

```
if ( current_user_can('read_post', $post_ID) ) {
    // do something
}
```

No role has this capability. It will be mapped to `read_posts`, `read_private_posts` or even other set of native capabilites depending on the context. Is current user the author of this post? Is this post private? What is the post status? It will do all verifications, even if the post has a custom post status.

Apparently, this type of verification, using this meta_cap, will only work when checking upon a specific user.

What about anonymous user?

Is there a way to use something similar to `current_user_can('read_post', $post_ID)` that will work when there is no current user?

Of course I could do all the checking myself. Is the post public or not? and so on. But my question is, is there a way to do so  whithout having to repeat all the logic that the `map_meta_cap` filter for `read_post` already implements so well?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. With WordPress, you don't have control on visitors (anonymous user). The only control you have with `is_user_logged_in()` to check user logged in or not. You can prevent posts from visitors.

Also, you can create a cookie or local storage based function (for control how many posts they visit) and integrate this function with `is_user_logged_in()`.